# GearVR with glsurfaceview?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, opengl-es, arcore, gear-vr

I'm having some problem for developing GearVR applications with ARCore,

In my application, I want to use function from ARCore which needs GLContext,
and I don't have to draw some object with it. ARCore just need context of OpenGL.

I tried to make small size glsurfaceview on it, to hide surfaceview and draw my origin contents,
but GearVR basically uses layout with xml format which includes

```
<lense name = "s8">
<vr-app-settings ~~blah blah
```

these descriptions and setMain function from GVRAcitivity in GearVR SDK make view from this xml,
So I cannot include glsurfaceview in it like normal android xml layout.

```
setMain(main,"gvr_s8.xml");
surfaceView = new GLSurfaceView(this);
setContentView(surfaceView);
```

I tried in this way but in this way I can only see surfaceView on my app not "gvr_s8.xml"

If I change it's order like this,

```
surfaceView = new GLSurfaceView(this);
setContentView(surfaceView);
setMain(main,"gvr_s8.xml");
```

My application doesn't includes GLcontext.

Is there any solutions for this situation?

***Sum up***

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4EWPUdE_kqU in this video,
- He uses Unity but I'd like to implement this in android studio
- I tried to use ARCore, GearVR view in parallel with GeaVR view, and hided ARCore camera
- But in using ARCore, GLContext is needed and, I can use GLcontext with GearVR view

Thank you for your helps.